# Invoking a Handler related to a specific web service call in axis2

Tags: soap, apache-axis

I am using Axis2 for my webservices creation. I need to validate the received soap request(is it complain with defined xsd schema).

For this I am using Handlers in axis2.

Now my problem is that how can i specify diffrent handlers which are psecific to diffrent webservice calls(in services.xml).

For example for create user i will user a enp as http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/createUser

and for updateUser i will invoke http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/updateUser.

For each invokatioon hadlers must be different.

Can any one give any suggestions on this regards.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do what you describe is to implement a module and then to engage this module(s) in your services.xml. You can see a detailed example here: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/modules.html The pocess in short is:

> 1. Create the Module Implementation
> 2. Create the Handlers
> 3. Create the module.xml
> 4. Modify the "axis2.xml" (if you need custom phases)
> 5. Modify the "services.xml" to engage modules at the deployment time.
> 6. Package in a ".mar" (Module Archive)
> 7. Deploy the module in Axis2

Engaging the module in your services.xml is as simple as:

> < module ref="logging" />

Please note that a module might be engaged per operation. Also note this thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-user@ws.apache.org/msg06058.html

> So the recommended way is to make a
>   module with the necessary handlers and
>   the capability to add handlers in
>   services will be completely removed in
>   the next release.

I hope this clears things.

Cheers!

Comment: why module.xml and not services.xml??